# Resque workers do not start properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, resque

I use devise and I can send mails with resque. I use this wiki:
[How To: Send devise emails in background (Resque, Sidekiq and Delayed::Job)](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Send-devise-emails-in-background-%28Resque,-Sidekiq-and-Delayed%3a%3aJob%29)

I have jobs in queue but no workers. Do I have to create task, or workers?

Comment: Just want to make sure -- are you running the resque workers: `QUEUE=* rake resque:work` ?

Comment: `rake aborted!`
`Don't know how to build task 'resque:work'`Do I have to create task for worker?

Comment: No, you just need to instal resque. Is it in your Gemfile? did you run `bundle install`? https://github.com/defunkt/resque

Comment: yes, I ran `bundle install` and `bundle update` too. It add "job" to queue, but don't do it, only push to queue.

Comment: [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/ItnfZ.png)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

OK, try adding this to your Rakefile:

```
require 'resque/tasks'
```

Then run your jobs:

```
QUEUE=* rake resque:work
```

Comment: thank you, now, this error: `No such file to load -- devise/confirmations_controller`

Comment: I add lines from [this](https://gist.github.com/1316470) and It's working, maybe. Thank you

Comment: It sounds like you use an AppEngine gem in your app.  For the worker(s), use `QUEUE=* rake environment resque:work` especially if you're getting `eager_load` errors.